# MYSQL How to add corresponding values to another table?

Tags: mysql

Sorry for the vague question.
I'm trying to add ID from Table 1

| Fruit_Name | Fruit_ID |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 01 |
| Banana | 02 |
| Pear | 03 |
| Grape | 04 |

to table 2 ID part.

| Fruit_Name | Fruit_ID | Grown In |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple |  | Farm A |
| Pear |  | Farm B |
| Apple |  | Farm B |

I want to put the same Fruit_ID from Table 1 into Table 2. So that it looks like
| Fruit_Name | Fruit_ID | Grown In |
| --------   | -------- | -------- |
| Apple      | 01       | Farm A   |
| Pear       | 03       | Farm B   |
| Apple      | 01       | Farm B   |
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NGHg.png)

There are 35 rows in Table 1, and 300 rows in Table 2.
How do I do it?

I tried using
ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD FOREIGN KEY (Fruit_ID) REFERENCES Table1(Fruit_ID);

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Can't give you the exact command right now but I want to point out that your DB probably shouldn't be organized like that. Usually you'd want every fruit to have an id and then only use those IDs in other tables. So your second table isn't supposed to have the names of the fruits at all, but only their ids.

Comment: How do i do this? I left the names of fruits so that i can bring the id...

Comment: Please provide more information about structuring database and how it would solve the issue in this case

Answer (score 0):

`@Dom Anna`, this works.

```
UPDATE Table_2 
INNER JOIN Table_1
ON Table_2.Fruit_Name=Table_1.Fruit_Name
SET Table_2.Fruit_ID=Table_1.Fruit_ID;
```

It may need to add a primary key (detail_ID) for the Table 2.